# How to display number as text but allow use in calculation?

Tags: excel, formula

I'm using some data to make notes of things. I need the content of the cell to sometimes display as `3+2`; this then goes in a table and I'd also like to sum this to equal to `5`.

E.g.

`Name   Jan   Feb
 AAA    4     3+5
 BBB    4+2   3+3
 CCC    2     4
 Total  12    18`

Would this be possible at all?

Comment: Are you allowed to use VBA?

Comment: @Djuka, I was actually hoping for a simple formula but happy to use VBA if that's not so simple... Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple function in VBA which can evaluate expressions:

```
Function EVAL(expression) As String
    EVAL = Evaluate("" & expression)
End Function
```

Then in cell you can use it as formula like this:

```
 =EVAL(C2)  // Where C2 value is 3+2
 =EVAL(3+2) // Or directly
```

Example:

[image]

You can use the expression `3+2` in cell where you want to show it and then use `EVAL` function in a table where you want to show the value of that expression.

Code screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *Formulas menu* => *Formula Auditing* => **Show Formulas**.

To show `3+2`. When you want to sho just `8` you can se the same button.

Comment: Is there a way to limit the cells in which this function would affect? I'd prefer not having to continually toggle for the formats... Thanks though, that's really helpful.

Comment: Or you can press CTRL + ` (grave accent) to display or hide formulas.

Comment: @kitarika, unfortunately this work only with the whole sheet and you can't select a single range. You have different options. The easiest is to put all the data you want to show the formula on a single sheet and the rest into another one. Another way is to build a small macro which add and remove a "'" before the formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but you have to do it for every formula by hand:

In cell `B2` you have your formula `3+2` as text. In cell `C3` you define a name, what you find in the formula tab of the ribbons, say "calc". In the dialogue, where you define the name, you have to write `=eval(B2)` in the field "refers to". And finally you have to write in the cell `C3` `=calc`, so you get the desired result.

*Hint:* Unfortunately I have only german excel, so I hope I guessed the english terms correct.